# Issue when trying to read SD card in Ubuntu 20.04.4 on Macbook Pro

Tags: sd-card

I am trying to read from my camera's SD card. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, on a Macbook Pro 2012.

I have inserted the card with a terminal open displaying the output of "tail -f /var/log/syslog"

Here is the output of the terminal after removing and inserting the card:

```
Jul 22 11:35:25 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1506.604728] mmc0: card aaaa removed
Jul 22 11:35:51 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1532.336269] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDXC card at address aaaa
Jul 22 11:35:51 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1532.337871] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC64G 59.5 GiB (ro)
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508270] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508289] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508368] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x000010c8 | Version:  0x00001502
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508375] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508384] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508392] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1ff70000 | Host ctl: 0x0000001f
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508400] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508408] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508415] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508421] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x03ff008b | Sig enab: 0x03ff008b
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508428] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508434] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508440] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508446] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x00000900
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508453] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508456] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000804b
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508468] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0x000000011039f204
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508469] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508514] mmc0: Unexpected interrupt 0x04000000.
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508519] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508525] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001502
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508531] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508538] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000033
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508544] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1ff70001 | Host ctl: 0x0000001f
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508549] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508556] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508562] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508568] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x03ff008b | Sig enab: 0x03ff008b
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508574] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508582] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508589] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000c1a | Max curr: 0x00000000
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508597] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x00000900
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508605] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508610] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508621] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0x000000011039f204
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro kernel: [ 1542.508623] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jul 22 11:36:01 matthew-MacBookPro fwupd[8611]: 10:36:01:0514 FuEngine             failed to add device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.1/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/block/mmcblk0: failed get ffu_capable for (null)
```

Here is the output of lsblk:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 186.9M  1 loop /snap/audacity/992
loop1     7:1    0 186.9M  1 loop /snap/audacity/971
loop2     7:2    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop3     7:3    0 228.1M  1 loop /snap/blender/2578
loop4     7:4    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2409
loop5     7:5    0 221.7M  1 loop /snap/code/102
loop6     7:6    0   222M  1 loop /snap/code/101
loop7     7:7    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2538
loop8     7:8    0   277M  1 loop /snap/gimp/380
loop9     7:9    0  70.4M  1 loop /snap/core22/188
loop10    7:10   0 251.5M  1 loop /snap/deja-dup/552
loop11    7:11   0 113.9M  1 loop /snap/core/13308
loop12    7:12   0   114M  1 loop /snap/core/13425
loop13    7:13   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop14    7:14   0  11.8M  1 loop /snap/nmap/2650
loop15    7:15   0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1518
loop16    7:16   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop17    7:17   0  70.4M  1 loop /snap/core22/165
loop18    7:18   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop19    7:19   0 260.7M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop20    7:20   0 254.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/106
loop21    7:21   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop22    7:22   0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1581
loop23    7:23   0 391.3M  1 loop /snap/gimp/383
loop24    7:24   0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop25    7:25   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop26    7:26   0   140K  1 loop /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop27    7:27   0 228.1M  1 loop /snap/blender/2474
loop28    7:28   0  11.8M  1 loop /snap/nmap/2655
loop29    7:29   0 565.5M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/291
loop30    7:30   0 400.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop31    7:31   0 111.1M  1 loop /snap/simplenote/524
loop32    7:32   0 565.5M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/286
loop33    7:33   0  64.9M  1 loop /snap/sublime-text/112
loop34    7:34   0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
loop35    7:35   0 111.1M  1 loop /snap/simplenote/544
loop36    7:36   0 169.4M  1 loop /snap/spotify/60
loop37    7:37   0 169.6M  1 loop /snap/spotify/58
loop38    7:38   0  64.7M  1 loop /snap/sublime-text/110
loop39    7:39   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop40    7:40   0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16010
loop41    7:41   0  54.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558
sda       8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2    8:2    0 223.1G  0 part /
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
mmcblk0 179:0    0  59.5G  1 disk
```

Would anyone have a suggestion for how I might be able to mount the card?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but also not provide details seen by `lsblk` or `blkid` that I'd more likely look at to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, post edited to include suggested info.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround from the bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1307674?comments=all works for me, but I needed to change the file name to include the extension .conf, e.g. sdhci.conf.

The modified workaround:

```
Add the following to /etc/modprobe.d/sdhci.conf:

  options sdhci debug_quirks2=4

Re-generate initrd:

 sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

Reboot or reload sdhci module:

 sudo rmmod sdhci-pci sdhci
 sudo modprobe sdhci
 sudo modprobe sdhci-pci
```